# What algorithm is clique_number using?

Tags: python, igraph

What is the algorithm behind [python-igraph's clique_number()](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#clique_number) function? It is obviously not a brute-force method given it's good performance.

Even clicking on the "source code" link does not seem to reveal it. Is this explained somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: "It is obviously not a brute-force", don't be so sure. Getting cliques is an NP-complete problem, no polynomial time solution exists.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ If it was a brute-force method, there would be absolutely no chance for it to finish on million-scale graphs in reasonable time which it currently does, exactly for the reason you mention.

Comment: Nice, did not know that! Graph modules are a wonderful thing...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Indeed :-) Hence, I really wonder what the algorithm used is. It compares very well against branch and bound and other methods as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clique_number` corresponds to the C [`igraph_clique_number`](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Cliques.html#igraph_clique_number), with worst-case complexity O(3^(|V|/3)). `igraph_clique_number` [iterates over all maximal cliques](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/0.7.1/src/cliques.c#L848) and finds the biggest size.

The algorithm used for finding all maximal cliques is version-dependent. The [docs](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Cliques.html#igraph_maximal_cliques) for the related `igraph_maximal_cliques` say

> The current implementation uses a modified Bron-Kerbosch algorithm to find the maximal cliques, see: David Eppstein, Maarten Löffler, Darren Strash: Listing All Maximal Cliques in Sparse Graphs in Near-Optimal Time. Algorithms and Computation, Lecture Notes in Computer Science Volume 6506, 2010, pp 403-414.
>
> The implementation of this function changed between igraph 0.5 and 0.6 and also between 0.6 and 0.7, so the order of the cliques and the order of vertices within the cliques will almost surely be different between these three versions.